# I want to test for internet connection and exit if it fails but asynchronous nature of alertdialog giving me grief

Tags: android

I have an app that has multiple tabs (all webview fragments).  I'm using a ViewPager and it works great except for one problem.

I want to test for internet connectivity.  I can do this using the following code:

```
    public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I then call this method from within my my onCreate method like so:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up the view pager
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set up action bar
    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    //bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Test for internet connectivity
    if(!isOnline())
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("You must be connected to the internet via wifi or 3g/4g.  Please connect and load the application again.")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       SynergyWorldwideActivity.this.finish();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    ...
```

The problem is that if I load the AlertDialog, it isn't modal and keeps on going through the onCreate method, creating tabs etc...  What I want to do is halt the application and exit gracefully if there isn't an internet connection.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
if(!isOnline())
    {
```

Right after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

And then put an else block with the rest of the onCreate code.

Also create an `onPause` method with the following

```
if(this.alert != null) {
    this.alert.dismiss();
}
```

Of course,

`alert` must be an instance attribute.